# (Python Selenium) Even though I didn't write the function ".close()" on Selenium, The browser is being closed by itself

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By as by
import time
import os
import idpas

os.chdir("C:/Users/ben/Desktop/Yeni klasör")

class browser:
    def __init__(self,link):
        self.link = link
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.goInstagram(self)

    def goInstagram(self):
        time.sleep(3.5)
        self.browser.get(self.link)
        time.sleep(3.5)
        browser.login(self)

    def login(self):
        id = self.browser.find_element(by.NAME,"username")
        password = self.browser.find_element(by.NAME,"password")
        log_in = self.browser.find_element(by.XPATH,"//*[@id='loginForm']/div/div[3]")

        id.send_keys(idpas.id)
        password.send_keys(idpas.password)
        log_in.click()
        time.sleep(1)

    def go_to_profile(self):
        goProfile = self.browser.find_element(by.XPATH,"//*[@id='f2079fe6736dc34']/div/div/a")
        goProfile.click()
        browser.getFollowers(self)

    def getFollowers(self):
        getTheFollowers = self.browser.find_element(by.CSS_SELECTOR,"_aacl _aaco _aacw _aacx _aad7 _aade")
        with open("C:/Users/ben/Desktop/Yeni klasör/followers.txt","w") as f:
            for i in getTheFollowers:
                f.write("\n")
                f.write(i.lower())

browser("https://www.instagram.com")
time.sleep(100000)
```

Hello everybody. As I wrote in the title, I am having trouble with Selenium in Python.
If I don't write those codes that I wrote above in a class, The browser isn't closed by itself.
But, I wanted to write those codes in a class. I am really about to cry due to my anger.
I am trying to fix it for 2 hours, but my effort could do nothing to those codes.
Please help me about this.

My codes are above.

Comment: By the way, I am sorry, I couldn't fix the locations of the codes. I am a new user here.

Comment: it's a little confusing that the class and webdriver object are both called "browser"... but seems like you could just do self.browser.quit().  (Or make a method in the class for quitting...)